# Need to create .htaccess and GET method

Tags: php, .htaccess, clean-urls

I want to create a url like

```
http://website.com/users/6663675?tab=profile
```

From a Clean url which has already made from index page

```
http://website.com/users/6663675/
```

Where htaccess is as

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?page=$1&uid=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: check your regex ... you miss **/** at the end

Comment: Which you probably want to make optional, so `/?`.

Comment: Also it is questionable if you really want to accept letters in that expression. Your example suggest purely numerical user ids...